# Proof by induction - $3.2 *10^{-6} * n! - 352.5 \le n!$

Tags: proof-verification, induction

This is a topic I find very hard. Could somebody please help me with this proof?

Prove by induction:

$3.2 *10^{-6} * n! - 352.5 \le n!$ for all $ n \ge 0 $

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: It's a silly problem for induction: $3.2\times 10^{-6}\times n!-352.5\leq 3.2\times 10^{-6}\times n!\leq n!$. Done. If you want to learn induction, you can always learn it from much better examples on this site.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show that the inequality holds for $n=1$. Assume it is fulfilled for $n\in \mathbf N$ and show that the inequality is also true if you replace $n$ by $n+1$.

Comment: Hi @yurnero, I agree it is a bit silly, but I need a formal proof, as this is for a math paper that I am writing.

Comment: @NiklasHebestreit I got up to the inductive step, but I could not prove this to be true for n+1. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: start with n = 0 - is it true?  Then if it is true for n, it has to be true for n+1 due to the rules of inequalities where n > 0, i.e. a>b implies na > nb for n>0 - you've got to start at n=0 BTW, not n = 1 - otherwise you need to go back and prove n=0 as a special case

Answer (score 0):

This example is not the best one to use and learn induction. The case $n=0$ is obviously fulfilled. Assume the inequality holds for $n\in \mathbf N_{>0}$. Then by the induction hypothesis
$$ \frac{3.2}{10^6}\cdot (n+1)! -352.5 = \frac{3.2}{10^6}\cdot n! -352.5 + \frac{3.2}{10^6}(n+1) \stackrel{\text{I.H.}}{\leq} n! + \frac{3.2}{10^6}(n+1) \stackrel{(\star)}{<} n! + n+ 1< (n+1)!$$
In $(\star)$ we used $\frac{3.2}{10^6} <1$. The last inequality can be proofed again by using induction but there might be better ways.

Comment: I don't think OP is trying to learn induction as much as apply it (he mentioned for a math paper he is writing.)